# Bash script does not output any data in tempfile

Tags: bash, shell

This is the code i use, i want to collect data from 4 logfile(s) in one file, then sort it and print the temp filename.

```
#!/bin/bash

TEMPFILE=$(mktemp)
USER=$1

# Check for input
#if [ -z $1 ]; then echo "Give me one username or mail address please..."

# Fill file with user history
cat /var/log/messages | grep $USER >> $TEMPFILE
cat /var/log/maillog | grep $USER >> $TEMPFILE
zcat /var/log/messages*gz | grep $USER >> $TEMPFILE
zcat /var/log/maillog*gz | grep $USER >> $TEMPFILE

# Sort by date
cat $TEMPFILE | sort -k1M -k2n -k3n > $TEMPFILE

echo $TEMPFILE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat` and `zcat` everywhere are useless and you cannot redirect to same file you're reading, that will get you a 0 byte file.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

TEMPFILE=$(mktemp)
user="$1"

# Check for input
#if [ -z $1 ]; then echo "Give me one username or mail address please..."

# Fill file with user history
grep "$user" /var/log/messages >> $TEMPFILE
grep "$user" /var/log/maillog >> $TEMPFILE
zgrep "$user" /var/log/messages*gz >> $TEMPFILE
zgrep "$user" /var/log/maillog*gz >> $TEMPFILE

# Sort by date
sort -k1M -k2n -k3n "$TEMPFILE" > "$TEMPFILE.tmp"
mv "$TEMPFILE.tmp" "$TEMPFILE"

cat "$TEMPFILE"
```

PS: Don't use upper case `USER` as variable run otherwise you will overwrite shell provide value for this variable. In general it is not recommended to use all uppercase variables in your script.

Comment: You could do both `grep` in one command, same with `zgrep` and you could mess with stdout so you don't get multiple opens, but it would make the script more difficult to read and I doubt it would save you much, if anything.  Only other thing, the question wants to print the temporary file **name** but you print (`cat`) the file itself.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Last `echo` wasn't serving any purpose as that could be done right after `mktemp` command. I assumed OP wants to see the final output that's why `cat` instead of `echo`